# Black screen in OpenGL on some machines (PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR/SwapBuffer?)

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, pixelformat

I've written an OpenGL application which will crash on some machines (on my own test machines it runs: Windows 8, Windows 7, Windows Vista (x86) - but on some client machines with Windows Vista (x86) it crashes) - I don't know yet why exactly, but I downgraded the application to an empty skeleton, which will just do `glClear()`. Then the application runs at least without crash (OpenGL context could be created, glew could be loaded), but the screen is not cleared in the specified `glClearColor` color. I suspect some issue in either my `PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR` or `SwapBuffer` doesn't work as expected there.

My code (I left out the windows creation and `main()` for simplicity):

```
hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
int   pf;
PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
memset(&pfd, 0, sizeof(pfd));
pfd.nSize  = sizeof(pfd);
pfd.nVersion  = 1;
pfd.dwFlags   = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL;
pfd.iPixelType   = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
pfd.cColorBits   = 32;

pf = ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd);
if (pf == 0) {
  MessageBox(NULL, "ChoosePixelFormat() failed:  "
 "Cannot find a suitable pixel format.", "Error", MB_OK); 
} 
if (SetPixelFormat(hdc, pf, &pfd) == FALSE) {
  MessageBox(NULL, "SetPixelFormat() failed:  "
 "Cannot set format specified.", "Error", MB_OK);
} 
DescribePixelFormat(hdc, pf, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR), &pfd);
hglrc = wglCreateContext(hdc);
if(!wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hglrc)){
  MessageBox(NULL, "wglMakeCurrent() failed:  "
 "Cannot make context current.", "Error", MB_OK); 
}
GLenum err = glewInit();
if (GLEW_OK != err){
  /* Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong. */
  fprintf(stdout, "Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
}
fprintf(stdout, "Status: Using GLEW %s\n", glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION));
```

This code outputs: "Status: Using GLEW 1.10.0"
My main loop then:

```
while(true){
  timeDuration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double> >(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - lastTime);
  lastTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  time += timeDuration.count();
  glClearColor(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  SwapBuffers(hdc);
  while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)){
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
}
```

On my own machine I receive an gray screen (as expected) - but on the machines where my original program crashed, the screen is just black (but none of the MessageBoxes appear and the output is also: "Status: Using GLEW 1.10.0"). So I can't see any evidence for an error - but the output is different and `glClearColor()` seems to be ignored.

Any ideas on how I could hunt down this issue further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm still not sure why exactly it did run on my machine before, but the issue was the line:

```
pfd.dwFlags   = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL;
```

after changing it to:

```
pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
```

it did run anywhere. I didn't specified double buffering in the `PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR` and that seemed to bring strange issues with it (worked on my machine for some reason - but not on others).

Comment: What do you mean you are not sure what you did? :) You requested a pixel format with double-buffering, rather than relying on the off chance that the driver simply hands you one. You should always request double-buffering when you actually ***need*** double-buffering (which on modern versions of Windows is always due to the compositing window manager).

Comment: I meant I'm not sure why it worked without requesting a double-buffering - but that makes sense: thanks for clarifying!